# Executing program from command line

Tags: ruby

I have done a program that sends requests to a url and saves them in a file. The program is this, and is working perfectly:

```
require 'open-uri' 

n = gets.to_i 
out = gets.chomp
output = File.open( out, "w" )

for i in 1..n
  response = open('http://slowapi.com/delay/10').read
  output << (response +"\n")
  puts response
end

output.close
```

I want to modify it so that I can execute it from command line. I must run it like this:

```
fle --test abc -n 300 -f output
```

What must I do?

Comment: I do not understand what you exactly want but tell you you can use `irb` to run each and every line of your code

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'open-uri'
require 'optparse'

# Prepare the parser
options = {}
oparser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: fle [options]"
  opts.on('-t', '--test [STRING]', 'Test string') { |v| options[:test] = v }
  opts.on('-n', '--count COUNT', 'Number of times to send request') { |v| options[:count] = v.to_i }
  opts.on('-f', '--file FILE', 'Output file', :REQUIRED) { |v| options[:out_file] = v }
end

# Parse our options
oparser.parse! ARGV

# Check if required options have been filled, print help and exit otherwise.
if options[:count].nil? || options[:out_file].nil?
  $stderr.puts oparser.help
  exit 1
end

File::open(options[:out_file], 'w') do |output|
  options[:count].times do
    response = open('http://slowapi.com/delay/10').read
    output.puts response # Puts the response into the file

    puts response # Puts the response to $stdout
  end
end
```

Comment: @Skynet then you should follow [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs) on how to register `.rb` files to be opened by the ruby binary. I am not aware of any other way. If you don't want the .rb suffix, you might need to be reqired to wrap your script call in a bach file. I am not a windows user, so I don't know the details.

Comment: can you update your code with an example of my code ? I don't understand exactly, how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more idiomatic way of writing your code:

```
require 'open-uri' 

n = gets.to_i 
out = gets.chomp

File.open(out, 'w') do |fo| 

  n.times do
    response = open('http://slowapi.com/delay/10').read
    fo.puts response
    puts response
  end

end
```

This uses `File.open` with a block, which allows Ruby to close the file once the block exits. It's a much better practice than assigning the file handle to a variable and use that to `close` the file later.

How to handle passing in variables from the command-line as options is handled in the other answers.

Comment: There's a small typo in the code example:`n.times` should be `n.times do`. I tried to edit it, but it wouldn't let me because the edit was under 6 characters. :(

Comment: @destielstarship, It's good that it didn't let you. It's considered bad form to edit people's code. Instead you should simply point it out in a comment. It's OK to adjust spelling, grammar and content for clarity but code and data are sacred.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that SO convention! I apologise. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to save you program in a file, add `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` at the top and `chmod +x yourfilename` to be able to execute your file.

Now you are able to run your script from the command line.

Secondly, you need to modify your script a little bit to pick up command line arguments. In Ruby, the command line arguments are stored inside `ARGV`, so something like

```
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

allows you to retrieve command line arguments.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I also believe, they could just use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, but otherwise it is a good remark in case ruby was installed through MRI or similar.

Comment: Walking through `ARGV` is definitely old-school. Don't do it unless you absolutely have to. Instead, take advantage of using Ruby's built-in [Option Parser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/index.html) class.